# How to resolve a circular dependency in AWS SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I have a SAM template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Description: |
  Some infrastructure

Resources:
  S3HomeBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: the-site-home
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
  BucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: S3HomeBucketPolicy
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObjects
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: '*'
            Action: 's3:GetObject'
            Resource: !Join
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                - !Ref S3HomeBucket
                - /*
      Bucket: !Ref S3HomeBucket
  homePageDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
        - DomainName: !Join [ "", [!Ref S3HomeBucket, ".s3.amazonaws.com"]]
          Id: myS3Origin
          S3OriginConfig:
            OriginAccessIdentity: origin-access-identity/cloudfront/my-id
        Enabled: 'true'
        Comment: the static home page cdn
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        Aliases:
        - the.info
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
          - GET
          - HEAD
          - OPTIONS
          TargetOriginId: myS3Origin
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: 'false'
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
        PriceClass: PriceClass_100
        ViewerCertificate:
          CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: 'true'
  CloudfrontInvalidatingFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Handler: invalidateStaticFiles.handler
      Timeout: 60
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaExecute
        - Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'cloudfront:CreateInvalidation'
              Resource: !Join
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:cloudfront:'
                - !Ref AWS::Region
                - ':'
                - !Ref AWS::AccountId
                - ':'
                - !Ref homePageDistribution
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DISTRIBUTION_ID: !Ref homePageDistribution
      Events:
        AnyChange:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref S3HomeBucket
            Events: s3:*
Outputs:
  SiteBucketName:
    Description: the name of the s3 bucket referenced by cloudfront
    Value: !Ref S3HomeBucket
    Export:
      Name: the-site-home-bucket-name
  CloudFrontId:
    Description: the id of the cloudfront distribution for the
    Value: !Ref homePageDistribution
    Export:
      Name: the-site-cloudfront-distribution-id
```

Running that I get:

> Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Circular dependency between resources: [CloudfrontInvalidatingFunction, BucketPolicy, CloudfrontInvalidatingFunctionAnyChangePermission, S3HomeBucket, homePageDistribution, CloudfrontInvalidatingFunctionRole]

I *don't think* that [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603137/how-to-resolve-a-circular-dependency-in-aws-cloudformation) applies

And I genuinely don't understand [this documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-circular-dependency-cloudformation/). It's not the same situation but I don't understand what it is proposing anyway.

What I'm trying to do is:

- have a bucket that will have static HTML,
- a cloudfront distribution that will sit in front of it
- and a lambda that will watch the bucket and invalidate the cache when files change

Is that possible?

(the [serverless application model github project issue template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/master/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md) points people here for help not github issues)

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case, if you would just hard-code the `DomainName` in the `homePageDistribution` resource -- basically removing the `!Ref S3HomeBucket` -- it would break the dependency cycle.

You could define a template parameter with the bucket name and use it throughout the template.

```
Parameters:
  ImagesBucketName:
    Default: the-site-home
    Type: String
```